# Salesforce Apex test class with null pointer exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to write a test method that requires me to generate an opportunity and all records associated with the opportunity. I keep getting null pointer exceptions in the strangest places.

```
public static void createOpp() {
    OpportunityEscalationtest.a = new Account(Name = 'SGC Test Account'
                                            , Type = 'Customer'
                                            , Phone = '(00) 0000 0000');

    insert OpportunityEscalationtest.a;

    OpportunityEscalationtest.c = new List<Contact>();      
    Contact newC = new Contact( FirstName = 'Jack'
                                , LastName = 'O\'Neil'
                                , Phone = '(00) 0000 0000'
                                , AccountId = OpportunityEscalationtest.a.Id);

    OpportunityEscalationtest.c.add(newC);

    newC = new Contact( FirstName = 'Samantha'
                        , LastName = 'Carter'
                        , Phone = '(00) 0000 0000'
                        , AccountId = OpportunityEscalationtest.a.Id);

    OpportunityEscalationtest.c.add(newC);

    newC = new Contact( FirstName = 'Daniel'
                        , LastName = 'Jackson'
                        , Phone = '(00) 0000 0000'
                        , AccountId = OpportunityEscalationtest.a.Id);

    OpportunityEscalationtest.c.add(newC);

    insert OpportunityEscalationtest.c;

    Contact priCont = [Select Id from Contact where FirstName = 'Jack' limit 1];
    OpportunityEscalationtest.a.GillForce__Primary_Contact__c = priCont.Id;

    OpportunityEscalationtest.o = new Opportunity( Name = 'Mountain Complex Water'
                                                 , CloseDate = system.today()
                                                 , StageName = 'Business Analysis'
                                                 , AccountId = OpportunityEscalationtest.a.Id);

    insert OpportunityEscalationtest.o;

    for (Contact cont : c) {
        OpportunityContactRole role = new OpportunityContactRole( ContactId = cont.Id
                                                                , OpportunityId = OpportunityEscalationtest.o.Id
                                                                , Role = 'Descision Maker');

        role.IsPrimary = (OpportunityEscalationtest.a.GillForce__Primary_Contact__c == cont.Id);

        insert role;
    }
}
```

The error is thrown somewhere between these 2 lines of code:

```
    insert OpportunityEscalationtest.c;

    Contact priCont = [Select Id from Contact where FirstName = 'Jack' limit 1];
```

I'm a bit stumped, unless i am mistaken this piece of code should be self contained. Any ideas would be excellent.

Comment: are you running this code as a test method, `testMethod public static void createOpp()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would try to set the API Version of your test class to 22.0 (Version Sttings Tab of your class body) and try to rund test again.

Comment: Please look at with http://salesforceblogger.blogspot.in/2012/02/sfdc-api-240-test-failure-issue.html

Comment: So a good answer would be to explain the main point that you read in the blog and reference the blog. Then people don't see a magical number offered as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error on line

```
Contact priCont = [Select Id from Contact where FirstName = 'Jack' limit 1];
```

It seams that insert fails (maybe due to some conditions in triggers). Or it may just doesn't insert one particular Contact with name Jack (maybe because of Last name).

What would I do if I were you. I would retrieve all Contacts and print them to the debug (or where it's easier for you). After this you will understand where is a problem.